# Check whether std::vector<bool> is comprised of only true values

Tags: c++, vector, stl, boolean, bitarray

What is the fastest way to determine whether a vector holding boolean values (which is typically optimized as a bit array) only holds true values? For small vectors, I think it might not be a bad idea to just compare the vector against another vector storing only true values (assuming we know the size of both vectors).

Comment: Use [std::all_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) everything else is probably just premature optimization unless you can prove that it's a bottleneck...

Comment: "The fastest way" can depend on C++ library implementation, compiler implementation, compiler optimisation level, target CPU, a whole lot of other things that makes this question pretty much unanswerable. "The fastest way" also comes across as a question of curiosity rather than a concrete problem you've faced. Is the obvious way (a simple `for` loop -- edit, or as Raphael Miedl commented, a standard library function that does that already) fast enough? Do you see an immediate problem with your implementation in the performance, in the generated code?

Comment: The fastest way is the first readable one you can think of. It increases the speed of development and maintainability. Usually it should be an algorithm from the standard library

Comment: If you really care, benchmark using `vector<bool>` + `all_of` against [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) and its `all` member function. While `vector<bool>` can't seem to make up its mind about whether to act as a bit-array or a generic `vector`, `dynamic_bitset` has the functionality you'd typically expect from a bit-array.

Comment: @hvd Not really -- it's just that std::vector<bool> is typically optimized as a bit array, so you would think that there's a fairly quick way to check whether they're all true or not. Preferably something short and readable.

Comment: @AnimatedRNG `vector<bool>` is more of a failed attempt at that. It uses a bitmap to safe space but doesn't expose any functionality to actually make use of that and gain speed. And it also breaks some container requirements thus getting the worst of both most of the time.

Comment: Probably, you can use std::bitset instead. It has such methods.

Comment: @AnimatedRNG Your compiler may optimise it to that already anyway. That's something you should be able to check yourself better than anyone here, since we don't know which compiler, standard library, etc. you're using.

Comment: @V.Kravchenko That sounds like a good idea -- I honestly just need a fairly readable way to test whether a container of < 15 boolean elements is completely true or false. Given that this should be a straightforward (and easy to optimize) operation, I was hoping it would also be fairly efficient as well.

Comment: Er... what, < 15 boolean elements and you're micro-optimising *that*?

Comment: @hvd Well this is more out of curiosity really, whether there exists a readable and efficient way to test whether a small boolean array is all true or not. I don't really need it to be optimal, I suppose, I'm just curious

Comment: If you can use a `bitset` instead you could do [`all`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/all_any_none)

Comment: The readable and efficient way is to just use the standard library algorithms that will be recognizable to all. Like `std::all_of`, `std::any_of` and friends. Don't reinvent the wheel - especially not for trivial things like this where performance doesn't really matter (or differences are so far into the statistical noise as to *not matter*). Sure, if used in a very hot inner loop that's executed millions of times each second, then *maybe* micro optimizing this makes sense. But I'd like to see some proof that that is the case first, before writing unreadable code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given `const vector<bool> foo(13)` use [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
cout << (find(foo.begin(), foo.end(), false) == foo.end()) << endl;
```

Or if you have [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you can [`none_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
cout << none_of(cbegin(foo), cend(foo), logical_not<bool>()) << endl;
```

Alternatively if you know your `vector`'s size at compile time you can use [`bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)'a [`all`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/all_any_none) method:

```
bitset<13> foo;

cout << foo.all() << endl;
```

[<kbd>Live Examples</kbd>](https://ideone.com/PZGMwL)