# c++/QT boolean vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, boolean

Looking for a boolean vector/array that returns true if all values are true and false if all values are false or mixed. Was going to create on object that did this but if something already exists I would be interested in using that.

In QT there is the QBitArray.  It seams the only way to check is to compare QBitArray::count() against QBitArray::count(bool on).

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/37842178/25507 answer your question?

Comment: Are you aware that Qt is old, and offers many classes for historical reasons? That's why QBitArray has the thread-unfriendly data sharing. In new code, consider `std::vector<bool>` or `std::bitset<N>`. Those are compatible with `std::all_of` and `std::any_of`.

Comment: Josh Kelly - Yes it does.  Wasn't able to find that for some reason.

Comment: MSalters.  Thank you for the clarification.